# Yii2 initialize datepicker to dynamic appended textfield via jquery

Tags: jquery, yii2

Sharing solution I'm using now:
make a ajax request to controller and append view file using renderAjax. 
Agree with you to use Yii way to initialize the datepicker@Muhammad Omer Aslam

I'm trying to fix this issue but still no luck.
If anybody will suggest then it will be great help.
I'm appending text field in `yii2` and initializing the datepicker.
I can see `hasDatepicker` class to input field but I can not see datepicker.
Please have a look

This is javascript code:

```
 $('#all_upcoming_audit_tr_container').on('focus','.upcoming_audit_date',function(){
              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              $("#"+id).datepicker();
        });
```

This is inspect element code:

```
<input id="upcoming_audit_start_date_74449" class="form-control upcoming_audit_date hasDatepicker" name="ManagersChecklistWeekly[any_upcoming_audits_text][74449][start_date]" type="text">
```

Comment: this is inspect element code:<input id="upcoming_audit_start_date_74449" class="form-control upcoming_audit_date hasDatepicker" name="ManagersChecklistWeekly[any_upcoming_audits_text][74449][start_date]" type="text">

Comment: Kindly donot add links of image.Post the code instead.

Comment: okay sorry for that:this is the code: $('#all_upcoming_audit_tr_container').on('focus','.upcoming_audit_date',function(){
                  var id = $(this).attr('id');
                  $("#"+id).datepicker();
            });

Comment: I suggest letting Yii handle it for you. Try using `http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html`

Comment: are you trying to add datepicker via `javascript`

Comment: Yes mate @MuhammadOmerAslam
and I have input field which are appended via javascript so I need to use jquery to initialize datepicker

Comment: okay `all_upcoming_audit_tr_container` is an input field? can you provide the relevant HTML, and how are you creating the text field , you said you are generating the input field dynamically, is it already existing in the document or created on runtime?

Comment: just updated the answer see the **EDIT** section

Comment: created run time mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the Yii way to initialize the datepicker so you don't have to worry about manually calling the javascript or loading the js sources, let Yii do the rest.

You can use the following ways if you are using

**`With Model & without ActiveForm*`**

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'from_date',
    //'language' => 'ru',
    //'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]);
```

**`Without Model & ActiveForm`**

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
    'name'  => 'from_date',
    'value'  => $value,
    //'language' => 'ru',
    //'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]);
```

Or

**`With Model & ActiveForm`**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'from_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::className(), [
    //'language' => 'ru',
    //'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]) ?>
```

**EDIT**

As per discussion you are trying to dynamically initialize the `datepicker`
via javascript so here it is the demo for initializing the datepicker on focus of input field

```js
$('#all_upcoming_audit_tr_container').on('focus', '.upcoming_audit_date', function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="all_upcoming_audit_tr_container">
  <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="upcoming_audit_date" />
</div>
```

Just make sure you are including all the libraries and `jquery` isnt included twice otherwise your script is fine. Look into console for any errors related to dual include of jquery.

Comment: Thanks mate to make an effort
but I want to add input fields dynamically
needs append the input field so I have to use jquery
will you please suggest some code with jquery

Comment: Thanks mate to get in touch with me again I checked all js already but I will check it again

Comment: Hi mate I checked js and it was fine

Comment: I opened chrome and tested again and It's working in chrome

Comment: same code not working in firefox 
currently I used input type="date" which is working in both

Comment: but somehow if we could get working datepicker in firefox and chrome both than that will be great help

Comment: dude my script is working in firefox too i just checked it what version of FF do you have mine is **`58.0.2 (64-bit)`** @MvVaghela , can you update your  browser to latest and check again

Comment: are you getting any exception in console?

Comment: same version mate FF 58.0.2(64-bit) and no exception in console

Comment: that is strange which OS windows or Ubuntu ? @MvVaghela and did you run this demo in FF

Comment: using windows 7

Comment: i am on windows too but on 10 do you have a live link to the app where you are using it.

Comment: and your jquery and query ui versions are also the same ? as in above demo

Comment: your code is fine and working but I checked all js and css(version also same 1.12.1) in my yii2 project. all are same but not working in FF:(

Comment: do you have a live link available to the application you are working on ?

Comment: and there is nothing on console? no exceptions? try opening up the inspector by hitting `F12` and check that your settings match this [**`image`**](https://imgur.com/a/QlSBv), so if there is some script missing and throwing 404 should be caught. @MvVaghela

Comment: no exception mate: see this image url:https://imgur.com/a/lW4FS
both input type=date and datepicker working in chrome and datepicker is not working in FF

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps:

```
$(document).on('focus','.upcoming_audit_date',function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: thanks mate for making effort,I tried this but no luck:)